# How to request full access to an external directory in unity on android 11 or higher?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, permissions

I have an app on Unity that should manage phone files to make some actions easier, this app works fine on android 10 and below, but on android 11-13 it just refuses to work, I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow request the ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION on click  button.

I tried adding the line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in the manifest but it didn't work for me.  I also tried to request this permission through a plugin written in android studio, but I also didn’t succeed, perhaps this is due to poor knowledge of java.
Hope you can help and thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing in your post what matches the subject.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.